# Change highlighting color of incremental search

Tags: colors, notepad++

Is there a way to change the color of the highlighted text when using the Incremental Search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)?

When using dark styles (Obsidian below), the highlighted text is not really visible:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Got the [answer](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11572/change-highlighting-color-of-incremental-search/3).*

The highlight color for the incremental search is the same as the one for the selected text. You can change it in the Style Configurator window by changing the background color of the "Selected text colour":

[image: screenshot]